# Passing arguments to JNI giving error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I just started to use NDK and i ran Hello_Jni and i know how that works but i wanted to try do something like this and cant get it to work (Im doing this manually)

simple.c

```
#include "simple.h"
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL
Java_com_example_Test_round_decimals (JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj, jdouble value, jint decimals) {
                  double m = pow (10, decimals);
     return (double) round (value * m) / m;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_Test_hello(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from ME!");
}
```

simple.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "math.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>


JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_example_Test_round_decimals (JNIEnv * env, jobject  obj,jdouble value, jint decimals);
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_Test_hello(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis);
```

Activity

```
public class Test{

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 double test = round_decimals(10.1234,2);
 double test2 = hello();    

         Log.i("Round","Number" + test); // i would like to get this

         Log.i("String","hello? " + test2); // this works it shows "Hello From ME!"

}
public native double round_decimals(double value, int decimals);
public native String hello();

       static {
           System.loadLibrary("simple");
       }

}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := simple
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := simple.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

android.mk, simple.c and simple.h are in JNI folder of my Activity.
And also running Build-ndk in folder of my Activity shows no errors

But when i try to build it on my tablet i get this error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:round_decimals
```

Comment: What exactly is your package name?

Comment: java.com.example But as i edited it works with simple String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Found the problem it was with **Java_com_example_Test_round_decimals** had to rename it to 
**Java_com_example_Test_roundDecimals** and with that i had to rename `public native double round_decimals(double value, int decimals);` to `public native double roundDecimals(double value, int decimals);`

Answer (score 1):

You generated the .h file from a version of the .java that had a package statement in it, then you modified the .java file to remove the package statement, then you compiled and ran, and nothing matched up.

There's something else wrong here. The method signature should be (JNIEnv*, jobject, jdouble, jint) if you've generated the files correctly.

Regenerate the .h file and adjust the .c file accordingly.

Comment: I didn't generate them I made them myself, But now I tried to add `String Hello();` (will edit my post) to show Hello from ME! and it works! But this double is giving me Errors.

Comment: Generate them. Use the tools. Make it up yourself and things go wrong. Things like this. It's pointless.

Comment: But what if i need to import code written in C and if it has many lines, shouldn't it be done by "hand" then, rather than generated? Just started with NDK so this might be a stupid question, but that was the reason i have done it like this

Answer (score 0):

You had an underscore (_) inside your method name and underscores are name delimiters in JNI convention.

Changing the java method name to camel case is a solution but you can also escape underscores using `_1` in your native method name, like so: `Java_com_example_Test_round_1decimals`.